# Invalid post type when click "Filter" or "Apply" button in WordPress admin Post list

Tags: posts, wp-admin

I need your help to resolve 1 Issue in Wordpress admin page.
I'm using WP 3.7.1 and twentytwelve template. I have some posts and pages. 
Currently, when I click Filter or Apply button in Post/Page list, it always shows the error "Invalid Post Type" and the URL looks like this .

> post_type=&_wpnonce=54fb54b00f&_wp_http_referer=%2Fwp-admin%2Fedit.php&action=-1&m=0&cat=0&paged=1&mode=list&action2=-1

I tried to active another template and it works fine!

Please help me to understand and fix this issue!!!
Thank you!!

Comment: Try disabling all plugins, reactivating the theme, and trying again. See if it works as expected. My guess is a plugin/theme conflict.

Comment: Thank for answering, but it may not solution, I deactivate all, but not effective :(